# Angular Dev Tools shows source as Window.addEventListener:message in Profiler

Tags: angular

I tried [Angular Dev Tools Extension](https://angular.io/guide/devtools) on a fairly complex Angular application. On the profiler tab, the moment I click "Start recording", even before I could move the cursor away from start button, I see there is a continuous stream of change detection cycles. The Source is reported as "Window.addEventListener:message". Please see the screenshot below
[image]

1. How can I find what could be causing these events and hence the numerous change detection cycles?
2. As seen in the screenshot there is a method called "changes" listed on the right under the component details. The CasePanelComponent does even have ngOnChanges() method, so what is being referred to here by "changes" method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Redux DevTools interferes with Angular Dev tools. And the only option available currently is to disable Redux Dev tools.

Please see
https://github.com/rangle/angular-devtools/issues/825 for more details.

Comment: I have this problem and I don't have ReduxTools. Firefox.

Comment: @hex Which problem are you referring to?

Comment: lot of detection cycles triggered by message

Comment: If you have a minimal, reproducible example, I can have a look.

Comment: To narrow down the problem disable all extensions except Angular devtools. Also, run profiling in incognito mode. If you still see the issue, it might be because of the code in your Angular project.

Comment: Wow, I went crazy by not finding the source ! Nice catch !